# NSUserDefaults unreliable?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults to store key/value pairs in my application. Below is the sample code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if !(ud.boolForKey("launched_before")) {
        print("first_launch")
        ud.setBool(true, forKey: "launched_before")
    } else {
        print("not_first_launch")
    }
}
```

The first time I launch the application, it prints "first_launch" as expected, and the second time I launch the application, it prints "not_first_launch" as expected too. However, if I continue re-launching the application by pressing Stop and Run button in the Xcode after a few times (maybe 4 to 20 times), the `boolForKey("launched_before")` will return false, which is wrong.
I am testing on my device (iPhone 6, iOS 9.3.1) and Xcode 7.3.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

NSUserDefaults does save unreliably, even worse that your just terminating it through Xcode stop/run.

Calling `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults().synchronize` will save the data.

Comment: But how come the second time it works as expected, which means setting boolean is successful, right?

Comment: this will help you understand the NSUserDefault how it works: http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/nsuserdefaults-some-pretty-good-practices/

Comment: @SuhasPatil thanks for the link, but it doesn't address my question why it works fine at the second time I run it, but may fail in subsequent runs. I don't think not calling synchronize() is the cause of the problem. Because the second time I run it, boolForKey() returns true which is correct, and it remains correct in subsequent runs until a few times later it suddenly returns false.

Comment: yeah i got you, what i think is the value is not reflected immediately in memory unless and until you did not call synchronize, till then it remain in cache memory and when it is cleared the respective value is also disappears!